# 'CGRectIntersectsRect' doesn't fire unless I add 'anchorPoint' code

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I use `CGRectIntersectsRect` with 2 sprites;

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(hero.boundingBox, oppo.boundingBox)){

 ...my code...
}
```

It was working fine in the previous version but somehow it just doesn't fire `CGRectIntersectsRect` now. I checked both versions, couldn't see any differences or problems. Now, it does not work unless I add;

```
hero.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
```

1. Do you know what can be the reason for that?
2. Does anchorPoint starts the boundingbox center from point(0,0) ? How can I use anchorPoint properly?

Thank you,

Comment: do `hero` and `oppo` have the same parent?

Comment: versions of what ? your app, Xcode, cocos2d ?